# I'm at a loss: Line 35:9: Parsing error: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <Switch>

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-router-dom

**My error message:**

```
  Line 31:16:  Parsing error: Unterminated JSX contents

  29 |           </Route>
  30 |         </Switch>
> 31 |       </Router>
     |                ^
  32 |     );
  33 |   }
  34 | }
```

**My code:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router,
         Switch,
         Route,
         Link
} from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
          <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
          </nav>
        //<Switch for Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/Login">
            <Login />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

import Home from './pages/Home';
import Login from './pages/Login';

export default App;
```

*It is saying I didn't terminate something, but I'm not seeing it. I've gone line by line like 20 times. Maybe I just need another pair of eyes, or perhaps I forgot something. Any feedback is much appreciated!*

Comment: I think JSX doesn't know this type of commenting on you code. Remove `//<Switch for Router>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//<Switch for Router>
```

If you're in the middle of JSX, this does not create a comment. It renders a string with two slashes, followed by an open tag for a `<Switch>` element, with props `for` and `Router` both `true`

If you want to keep the comment, change it to:

```
{/*<Switch for Router>*/}
```